# WebGL: Interacting with browser scripting unity engine (build problem)

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I try making a function that reloads the page for me (WebGL unity engine)
I used the Unity site itself: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html to create javescript code

Assets/Plugins/WebGL/MyPlugin.jslib :

```
var MyPlugin = {

 function reloadPage(){
        window.location.reload();
      }
};

mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, MyPlugin);
```

Then I call these functions from my C#

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void reloadPage();
```

but now when I try to build the project, gave me this error :

```
Failed process stderr log:
error: failure to execute js library "D:\NFT Creature Mixer\Project\Creature_Mixer\Assets\Plugins\WebGL\MyPlugin.jslib": SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier,,SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.load (eval at globalEval (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\src\compiler.js:105:8), <anonymous>:179:14)
    at JSify (eval at globalEval (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\src\compiler.js:105:8), <anonymous>:87:20)
    at D:\NFT Creature Mixer\Project\Creature_Mixer\Assets\Plugins\WebGL\MyPlugin.jslib (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\src\compiler.js:221:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
preprocessed source (you can run a js engine on this to get a clearer error message sometimes):
=============
var MyPlugin = {

 function reloadPage(){
        window.location.reload();
      }
};

mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, MyPlugin);

=============

Internal compiler error in src/compiler.js! Please raise a bug report at https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/ with a log of the build and the input files used to run. Exception message: "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" | SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.load (eval at globalEval (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\src\compiler.js:105:8), <anonymous>:179:14)
    at JSify (eval at globalEval (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\src\compiler.js:105:8), <anonymous>:87:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\src\compiler.js:221:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc.py", line 3063, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc.py", line 1780, in run
    final = shared.Building.emscripten(final, append_ext=False, extra_args=extra_args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\shared.py", line 2274, in emscripten
    emscripten._main(cmdline)
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 2233, in _main
    return temp_files.run_and_clean(lambda: main(
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\tempfiles.py", line 93, in run_and_clean
    return func()
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 2238, in <lambda>
    DEBUG=DEBUG,
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 2164, in main
    temp_files=temp_files, DEBUG=DEBUG)
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 86, in emscript
    glue, forwarded_data = compiler_glue(metadata, libraries, compiler_engine, temp_files, DEBUG)
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 218, in compiler_glue
    glue, forwarded_data = compile_settings(compiler_engine, libraries, temp_files)
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 541, in compile_settings
    cwd=path_from_root('src'), error_limit=300)
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.27f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\jsrun.py", line 132, in run_js
    raise Exception('Expected the command ' + str(command) + ' to finish with return code ' + str(assert_returncode) + ', but it returned with code ' + str(proc.returncode) + ' instead! Output: ' + str(ret)[:error_limit])
Exception: Expected the command ['C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.27f1/Editor/Data\\Tools\\nodejs\\node.exe', '--stack_size=8192', '--max-old-space-size=4096', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\Emscripten\\src\\compiler.js', 'C:\\Users\\aryan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpoqaf40.txt', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Audio.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\case_1174367_workaround.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\case_1179945_workaround.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\case_1187965_workaround.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\case_1208971_workaround.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Cursor.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Eval.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\FileSystem.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Logging.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Profiler.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\SystemInfo.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\UnetWebSocket.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Video.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\WebCam.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\WebRequest.js', 'D:\\NFT Creature Mixer\\Project\\Creature_Mixer\\Assets\\Web3Unity\\Scripts\\Library\\WebGL\\web3gl.jslib', 'D:\\NFT Creature Mixer\\Project\\Creature_Mixer\\Assets\\Plugins\\WebGL\\MyPlugin.jslib', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Hub\\Editor\\2020.3.27f1\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\Emscripten\\src\\library_pthread_stub.js'] to finish with return code 0, but it returned with code 1 instead! Output: // The Module object: Our interface to the outside world. We import
// and export values on it. There are various ways Module can be used:
// 1. Not defined. We create it here
// 2. A function parameter, function(Module) { ..generated code.. }
// 3. pre-run appended it, var Module = {}; ..generated
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Answer (score 1):

so stupid my javaScript code was wrong

```
var MyPlugin = {

 reloadPage: function (){
        window.location.reload();
      }
};

mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, MyPlugin);
```